Points with Z (depth) values in QGIS 3D view
If it is possible to visualize points (x,y) that have, in addition, z (depth) column, on that certain depth value, in QGIS 3D view, then how do I do it?
Perhaps a plugin has to be used, for that purpose, like for example Qgis2threesjs.
